# Apache In XAMP is not working ! !

Tags: apache

I keep getting the same error, I've tried changing the port via 'httpd.conf' many times, but it was useless, it keeps giving me this error. Any help is appreciated;

```
7:13:51 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
7:13:51 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:13:51 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:13:51 PM  [Apache]    Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
7:13:51 PM  [Apache]    and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache needs to use default ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS / SSL), you have two options, either you change the port number used by apache or disable services that your system is using those ports. I propose a solution that works on windows 7. 
you must disconnect the microsoft IIS server that listens on port 80 by default for this do the following: 
-accesses the command line CMD in administrator mode 
writes: net stop was 
-will you answer yes 
-you will answer a confirmation that the IIS has been disconnected 
And you can start apache on port 80

You may also have busy port 443 for another service your system for it through the control panel in the xampp apache config button choose .. Apache (httpd-ssl.config) and you replace occurrences of the number 443 by any other number, 444 for example, is only necessary in the lines that are not comments (comment lines starting with #)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this problem ..One of the main thing for this problem is about the port.If you are running another program  like skype etc which is blocking port 80 or 443.   then you've found your problem! Change apache's port settings to 81 and apache will work

Comment: I knew that before sending this post, that's not the solution.